# AJAX sending object with functions throws error at function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I have the following `Ajax`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Jeopardy/saveCategoryData',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: this.name,
            questions: this.question_array,
            sort_number: this.sort_number,
            game_id: game_id
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            this.id = data;
        }
    });
```

**Update This is the full class the ajax is apart of:**

```
function Category(name, sort_number)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.sort_number = sort_number;
    this.question_array = [];
    this.id = 0;
    /*
        Functions
     */
}

Category.prototype.saveCategory = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Jeopardy/createCategory',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax',
            name: this.name,
            sort_number: this.sort_number,
            game_id: game_id
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            this.id = data;
        }
    });
    $('.category_'+this.sort_number).each(function()
    {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        $(this).addClass('question');
    })
}

Category.prototype.submitCategory = function()
{

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Jeopardy/saveCategoryData',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                request: 'ajax',
                name: this.name,
                questions: this.question_array,
                sort_number: this.sort_number,
                game_id: game_id
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                this.id = data;
            }
        });
}

Category.prototype.addQuestion = function(question,index)
{
    this.question_array[index] = question
}
```

Where this.question_array is an array of `question` objects:

```
function Question(question, score)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.score = score;
    this.answer = [];

}

Question.prototype.getScore = function()
{
    return this.score;
}

Question.prototype.addAnswer = function(answer)
{
   this.answer.push(answer)
}
```

My answer object:

```
    function Answer(answer, is_correct)
{
    this.answer = answer;
    this.is_correct = is_correct;
}
```

When my `Ajax` submits i get an error at the function `addAnswer` saying: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening (i am fairly new to OOP in JavaScript)

**Update create.js (script that controls the objects)**

save question function:

```
function saveQuestion() {
    var question = new Question($('#txt_question').val(), current_money);
    var array_index = (current_money / 100) - 1;
    $('.txt_answer').each(function ()
    {
        var answer = new Answer($(this).val(), $(this).prev().find('input').is(':checked'));
        question.addAnswer(answer); // <-- Add answer
    })
    if(current_element.find('.badge').length == 0)
    {
        current_element.prepend('<span class="badge badge-sm up bg-success m-l-n-sm count pull-right" style="top: 0.5px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>');
    }
    addQuestionToCategory(question, array_index);
    questionObject.fadeOutAnimation();

}

function addQuestionToCategory(question, index) {
switch (current_category_id) {
    case "1":
        category_1.addQuestion(question, index);
        break;
    case "2":
        category_2.addQuestion(question, index);
        break;
    case "3":
        category_3.addQuestion(question, index);
        break;
    case "4":
        category_4.addQuestion(question, index);
        break;
}
```

}

And the function that calls the ajax on each category object:

```
    function saveGame()
{
    category_1.submitCategory();
    category_2.submitCategory();
    category_3.submitCategory();
    category_4.submitCategory();
}
```

Debug callstack:

```
Question.addAnswer (question.js:25)
n.param.e (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
(anonymous function) (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
n.extend.each (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
n.param (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
n.extend.ajax (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
Category.submitCategory (category.js:47)
saveGame (create.js:116)
onclick (create?game_id=1:182)
```

***UPDATE**

Okay something odd is going on if i change the addAnswer function to the following:

```
    Question.prototype.addAnswer = function(answer)
{
   if(this.answers != undefined)
   {
       this.answers.push(answer)
   }
}
```

It works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Alexander deleted his response, here is what I would suggest:

```
function Question(question, score)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.score = score;
    this.answer = [];
}

Question.prototype.getScore = function()
{
    return this.score;
}

Question.prototype.submitQuestion = function()
{

}

Question.prototype.addAnswer = function(answer)
{
   this.answer.push(answer)
}
```

Comment: Ive updated it so it looks like this but i am still getting the error

Comment: Can you show the line of code that actually adds the question and it's answer? That's where the problem is, I don't think this is related to Ajax or jQuery.

Comment: The add answer function is not called doing the Ajax function as you can see from my code :S

Comment: Do you want my call stack?

Comment: Somehow the .answer property of one of your Question objects is not being initialized, which does not make sense. It is there in the constructor... perhaps you are accidentally overwriting the .answer property somewhere?

Comment: Also make sure you have it has `.answer` OR `.answers` everywhere. If there is a single inconsistency, it will fail.